# Custom .NET Standard Nuget package not installing correctly

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard

I have a .NET Standard class library project with a number of POCO's. This project is built using TeamCity and published as a Nuget package using the built-in Nuget server.

The problem I'm having is when it's installed into my solution with a number of .NET Framework class library projects and ASP.NET MVC and Web API projects (set to .NET Framework 4.7.1), it seems to be stuck on an older version and is not recognising any new classes or methods I add to the project - e.g. NewMethod1()

**Project File for Nuget package**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461;net462;net47</TargetFrameworks>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>2.0.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <Description>Standard entities used within our systems</Description>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <Authors>Company X</Authors>
    <Company>Company X</Company>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

TeamCity is using the 'dotnet' restore, build & pack options.

The package is stored in my Nuget cache located in C:\Users\antho.nuget\packages. When I use Object Browser to inspect the dll, it contains the new classes and methods (e.g. NewMethod1()).

When I install this package into my .NET Framework solution, no errors occur during the installation. If I try and use the new method - NewMethod1() - the code doesn't compile.

If I create a brand new solution and ASP.NET MVC project and install the package, the new method can be used in code and it compiles successfully.

What could be causing the new version not to be installed correctly? It's tricky to provide a sample reproducing the issue because it seems to work in a new project.

**Update**

If I add a new project to the solution and install the Nuget package, it gets the latest version.

Project A

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoGuru.Shared.Utilities" Version="1.0.369" />

public class Class1
{
    public void Test()
    {
        "dfdfdfdf".SanitizeVehicleRego();
    }
}
```

Project B

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoGuru.Shared.Utilities">
  <Version>1.0.369</Version>
</PackageReference>

public class Class1
{
    public void Test()
    {
        "fdfdf".SanitizeVehicleRego();
    }
}
```

Project B compiles successfully and Project A doesn't. SanitizeVehicleRego() is a string extension method in the AutoGuru.Shared.Utilities package.

Comment: do you already try to clean the bin & obj folder of your Project A

Comment: Yes, already tried that

Answer (score 0):

My answer it quite big, so I add an answer instead of comment.

**Step 1**

Check the output when you restore the package, sometimes `dotnet restore` resolve an other version automatically ( you should have a warning for this kind of things in your console ).

**Step 2**

If any information was found in **Step 1**. Try to clean all your local nuget cache.

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```

I'm not sure if local nuget packages are under cache stategy. But if they are, it should resolve the correct version of your package.